# How to test scala case classes using Junit

Tags: scala, junit

Is it possible to write a test case for case classes? If so how to write a test case for case class in scala using Junit.

My Sample Case class

```scala
case class SampleClass(userId: Int, userName: String)
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want to test about your case class. I mean, it's just a data container with built-in conversion to string, structural equality and deconstruction. It's like asking how to test a `struct` in C ... There just isn't any behavior to test.

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible.

First of all, JUnit is simply a framework that allows for the creation and automated execution of test cases that run on a JVM.

There is even some support for the scala IDE plugin (see [here](http://scala-ide.org/docs/current-user-doc/features/test-finder/index.html)).

But also of course, JUnit is intended to be uses with Java source code.

Therefore you might be better of looking into frameworks that "fully" support the scala language - such as ScalaTest. But for the record: even the ScalaTest people have examples talking about JUnit and Scala - see [here](http://www.scalatest.org/getting_started_with_junit_4_in_scala).

Finally: before getting into the depths of testing frameworks you should rather learn about the basic of unit tests.

The question is not: "what framework do I use?" - you should start with: how do I write tests?

You see, in your example ... there isn't really much that you can test in the first place. A Scala case class has defined known semantics - there is no point in writing test cases to verify them. In other words: focus on understanding the "why" of unit tests, and the "what to test" before spending your time on the "what framework to use" part.

Comment: please let us know how to write testcase for Case Classes in scala

Comment: I suggest you read my answer again. You tell me what you think can be tested for case classes. There is nothing that is meaningful to be tested. The only possible test would be "is that class legal valid Scala source Code"? And that question is answered by the compiler, you don't use a unit test for stuff that the compiler tells you. And note that a downvote makes a really bad starting point asking a question.